# Code alignment in Clion

Tags: c++, clion

I updated my Clion and my code alignment settings changed. Before I had

[image: 1]

now I have

[image: 2]

How can I have my code like the first picture ? What settings to tweak ?

Answer (score 2):

Code style > c/c++ > binary expressions > align when multiline

Answer (score 0):

settings->editor->code style->tabs and indents

If it doesn't help, leave them a bugreport at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP

what's your CLion version btw?

Comment: mine is 145.972, latest stable and it works as in your first example.  Did you install EAP?

Comment: I am using the Qt predefined style and I have changed only a couple of options. What are you using ? I just downloaded Clion

Comment: Can you export your settings file > export settings and upload them somewhere for me to download ?

Comment: I found the problem after comparing defaults vs my settings. I posted an answer